# Soft question about the FTC

Tags: real-analysis, integration, soft-question

Is there a universal standard naming for the two parts of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus?

I've seen the First Fundamental Theorem of Calculus being referred to as the Second (e.g. Wolfram Mathworld), and the Second (in Wolfram Mathworld) as the First in e.g. Wikipedia, Spivak's Calculus book.

Comment: I've seen both too. Since these two opposite conventions are from widely reputable sources, I wouldn't expect a consensus.

Comment: Shall we try to introduce a naming? I suggest DI (derivative of integral) and ID (integral of derivative).